# What's the next step here to understand the existence and uniqueness theorem?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find an intuitive grasp of the existence and uniqueness theorem, but all the explanations online explain it using higher mathematics, which sort of defeats the purpose of explaining...

So I'm trying to piece it together myself and this is what I have so far:

I have a function $f(x,y)$, which is real-valued and continuous within some given rectangle on the xy-plane.  I like to imagine f to be a height map, or a surface here.  So, I have a surface $f(x,y)$, and $x$ and $y$ are independent.  So far so good.

Next, instead of thinking of it as a surface over $x$ and $y$, I can think of it as a set of $y$ functions in $x$.

This next part gets a bit shaky:
Now I'm given the problem to find a particular $y(x)$ where $y'=f(x,y)$.  Not completely sure here, but I think $y'$ is found by taking the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$, which is a still a function in $y$, which is a surface also?  So I have two surfaces now.  I'm guessing that if they don't cross over anywhere, there's no solution, but if they meet at a tangent, there's one solution, and if they meet at more than that then infinite solutions?

Then, I'll be given an initial condition which I use to identify the unique solution if it exists.

Is that roughly the idea, or am I way off?

Comment: Are you trying to understand why the hypotheses should imply the conclusion, or what the conclusion itself says?

Answer (score 0):

The better idea is to think of $f$ as a vector field $(1,f(x,t))$. That is, in every point $(x,y)$ there is a prescribed direction. Now you try moving in the x-y-plane always following the current direction of the vector field. The curve that you draw in the plane is then a solution curve of the ODE.

The direct numerical realization of this picture is the explicit or forward Euler method. Take the direction at the current point and follow this direction for the time-span $h$. At the next stop, restart, i.e., take the new direction, reorient and follow for a time-span $h$,...